# only submit is check box is checked

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<div id="checkbox">    
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</div>
```

i have the above code and need some sort of check so that the form only submits if at least one box is checked also wont submit if 2 boxes are checked, so only checks to make sure 1 is checked.

Many thanks

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: Use radiobutton ..

Comment: Firstly what have you tired that hasn't worked? Also, using numbers as ID's is a biiiig no no!

Comment: In HTML5 IDs are allowed to start with a number AFAIK

Comment: what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use radio buttons group. You may follow this [reference](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

With radio button, you don't need to use javascript. But if you insist to use checkbox, using javascript is one of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using Checkbox makes sense if you are interested in making user select one or more values. For your purpose I would recommend radio buttons

Use radio buttons instead of check boxes and give them all the same name. And then don't use javascript at all.

Comment: check my answer please,, (using checkbox)

Comment: Yes but why would you want to use checkbox?

Comment: because Dan Howes is asking for `input type="checkbox"` that's the only reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Use radio button

```
<div id="checkbox">   
<input type="radio" id="1" name="radio_button"/><br/>
<input type="radio" id="2" name="radio_button"/><br/>
<input type="radio" id="3" name="radio_button"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @pooshonk : thanx, copy paste error .. :D :D

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use a radio button? or add a class on this checkboxes (if you want checkbox) and deselect all `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript function:

```
<script>
function checkifclicked()
{

    //alert($('input[name=cb]').val());
    var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("cb");
    var okay=false;
    for(var i=0,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(checkboxs[i].checked)
        {
            okay=true;
        }
    }
    if(!okay){

        alert("Please check a checkbox");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>


<form name="send_email" id="send_email" action="send_email.php" onSubmit="return checkifclicked()" method="post">

<div id="checkbox">    
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="cb"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="cb"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="cb"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>


</form>
```

[Demo Here>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aUjP7Z)

Answer (score 0):

You should use radio button if only one of them should be checked.

```
<div id="checkbox">    
<input type="radio" id="1" name="somename"/>Label1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="2" name="somename"/>Label2<br/>
<input type="radio" id="3" name="somename"/>Label3<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WHDFt/

You also want to be sure that one of them is checked. There are some solutions for that.

1. Make a default check. For example you could by default make first radio checked. It is no posibility to uncheck radio buttons, so there always will be checked field.
2. You can validate this using JavaScript while submiting the form.

Answer (score 0):

give id to submit button for example:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Create"/>
```

js code:

```
$(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(){
      if($('#checkbox input:checked')){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   });
});
```

But using multi select is better idea for You

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('1').checked || document.getElementById('2').checked || document.getElementById('3').checked)
 {

     if((document.getElementById('1').checked && document.getElementById('2').checked ) || (document.getElementById('2').checked && document.getElementById('3').checked ) || (document.getElementById('1').checked && document.getElementById('3').checked ))
      {

         return false;
      }

      else
      {
          //dosomthing

      }

    }
```